# How can I fill the data frame NA value using data in another dataframe (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have got two data frames in Python, how can I fill the `NAN` value in `df1` using `df2`'s value? I want the final like `df3`, as seen below. I have tried several ways, but fail.

```
df3 = df1.update(df2)
```

or

```
df3 = df1.combine_first(df2)
```

I can not find a solution on it, anyone could help? How can I code this part in Python?

How can I fill the NAN value in DF1 using Df2 :

[image: how can i fill the NAN value in DF1 using Df2,]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have the right idea with `combine_first`, but need to align indices first via `set_index`:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Group': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                    'Key': ['AA1', 'AB2', 'AC3', 'BD4', 'BE5', 'BF6'],
                    'Value1': [np.nan, 20, 40, 60, np.nan, np.nan],
                    'Value2': [np.nan, 30, 50, 23, np.nan, np.nan]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Key': ['AA1', 'BE5', 'BF6'],
                    'Value1': [66, 20, 21],
                    'Value2': [33, 60, 70]})

res = df1.set_index('Key').combine_first(df2.set_index('Key')).reset_index()

print(res)

   Key Group  Value1  Value2
0  AA1     A      66      33
1  AB2     A      20      30
2  AC3     A      40      50
3  BD4     B      60      23
4  BE5     B      20      60
5  BF6     B      21      70
```

Comment: thanks a lot, work perfectly, saving me a lot of time. :)